# Can feature graphic image be changed after publishing the app?

Tags: android, google-play

Can feature graphic image be change in the same version or next version after it is published once?
There is one more unrelated question I have related to this. Is the grey background gradient added automatically to make white icons visible in icon and feature graphic image or does it have to be a part of image?

Comment: Just go in play console choose your app than go to Store Presence -> Store Listing, change than save it. Yeah you dont have to update the version.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can. Go to `Store Presence/Store Listing` to change it